# SQL running total from a count

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can one get a running total from a quantity that was calculated by a count?

```
select Hour, count(*) TotalPerHOur, sum(TotalPerHOur) TotalCumulative
from table1
group by Year, Month, Day, Hour
```

This is my query - but doesnt work...
Error I get is

> invalid column TotalPerHOur

Example of result table

```
HOUR    Total_per_Hour Total Cumulative
6:00-7:00   8                     8
7:00-8:00   13                    21
8:00-9:00   20                    41
9:00-10:00  22                    63
10:00-11:00 10                    73
11:00-12:00 23                    96
```

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: And the error which you are getting?

Comment: You have no order defined, so how is the order of the running total defined?

Comment: It would be the best if you could post some example data and expected results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT t1.Hour, count(*) TotalPerHOur, (
  SELECT count(*) 
  FROM table1 t2
  WHERE t2.Year <= t1.Year and t2.Month <= t1.Month and t2.Day <= t1.Day and t2.Hour <= t1.Hour
) TotalCumulative
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.Year, t1.Month, t1.Day, t1.Hour
```

In [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a747/1).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because `TotalPerHOur` is not yet defined. And you are using it to calculate `TotalCumulative`.

Following query should work:

```
SELECT 
    Hour, 
    TotalPerHOur, 
    sum(TotalPerHOur) TotalCumulative
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Hour, 
        count(*) TotalPerHOur
    FROM 
        table1 
    GROUP BY 
        Year, 
        Month, 
        Day, 
        Hour
)
```

Comment: I get an invalid syntax error when trying to use this code

Answer (score 0):

Following query will generate running total;

```
    WITH Base AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Year, Month, Day, Hour) RowNum,
    Year, Month, Day, Hour, count(*) as CountPerHour, sum(Total) as TotalPerHour FROM table1 group by Year, Month, Day, Hour
    )
    select T1.Year, T1.Month, T1.Day, T1.Hour, T1.CountPerHour, sum(T2.TotalPerHour) from BASE as T1
    join BASE as T2 on T2.RowNum <= T1.RowNum
    Group by T1.Year, T1.Month, T1.Day, T1.Hour, T1.CountPerHour
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically the database should optimize this query, so it shouldn't be a problem to count twice:

```
select Hour, count(*) TotalPerHOur, sum(count(*)) TotalCumulative
from table1
group by Year, Month, Day, Hour
```